# How to install a recently created dexterity product on the webserver?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I've made a plone 4 dexterity product but I don't know how to install it on my webserver.
I can install any other package using buildout -- however my addon is not posted on PyPI or a similar package index.

What is the best way to have this offline product working on a webserver?
Should I use the same way as in the development mode?

Comment: Do you have a programming question?

Comment: What's an "offline" pack or product? Why would it be different from any other?

Comment: I'm sorry, I used "pack" to describe a product and I said offline because the product is in a local source. I just didn't know how to publish the product but I already have a solution bellow. Thank you.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Please be patient with Plone-users, they are directed to SO from plone.org/support and might have quests which are not strictly programming related, TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question, you have an "egg" not hosted on Pypi or other compatible site.

The way we use is to put eggs in a local directory inside the buildout and add this directory to your `find-links` buildout section.

You can see how this works from the RedTurtle buildout here: https://github.com/RedTurtle/deployments.buildout.plone/blob/dc2808a0130d1132365b2a1216f8ef0742a96b2b/config/base.cfg#L14

Comment: Thank you keul, you solved the question! I have a little trouble with it because I'm new programming in Plone though my english is not so good. But every day I'm getting better ;) Thank you very much.

Comment: @RicardoR If keul's answered solved your quest, please accept it! TIA